# How to you use cache when offline

Tags: php, apache, http, offline-caching

I have a php webpage that I'd like to cache and use local storage when offline. When connected to wifi, the page loads fine. When I turn off my wifi, I get a HTTP ERROR 500, and the page will not load at all, even though I thought the html, css files would still be in the cache.
Is there a way to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: If you get a 500 status code, you get _something_ from a server. Means, you have some connection. Or your application displays this willingly without connecting to a server, but that would be actively misleading.

Comment: Bear in mind that "a server" can equally mean your local webserver, which is also capable of returning a 500 status code. It doesn't have to be a remote one.

Comment: Yep, I'm running it locally and I've no idea how to fix it. thanks for your help